# Find elements with a given difference in an array

Tags: c, arrays

### 1. Summary

#### 1.1. Language:C

I have an array like this {30, 220, 219, 220, 221}, and I have a difference value, let's suppose 9 (k=9).
I want to get all the integer elements of the array which have less than that difference. Then return the average of those valid values.

Note 1. size of array is not fixed. e.g. it could be like this:

{220, 219, 220, 30, 216, 224, 217} //larger array size

or {222, 220, 219, 220, 221} // all the values are within the difference

or {30, 66, 89, 220, 221} // more values are out of range

Note 2. duplicate elements should not be removed. Else, it could affect averaging section.

#### 1.2. Example:

Given array:{30, 219, 220, 221, 216, 220};

Difference = 9;
I am looking for average of 219,220,221,216,220 returned in integer, which is 219.

What I am doing is first finding indexes of eligible elements. Then removing duplicate of indexes, then averaging.

### 2. Background

I wrote the following code with help of examples I found on different pages, but there are some issues with it.

### 3. The code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>



int countPairs(int a[], int n, int k)
{
  printf( "n is %d \tand\t", n); //debug
  printf( "k is %d\n\n", k); //debug
//////////////////////////////////////// finding indexes ////////////////
//credit: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pairs-difference-less-k/
  int index[n*2];
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            
            if ((a[j] - a[i]) < k) {
                index[res] = j;
                printf("index[%d]= %d,\t", res, index[res]); //debug
                printf("(%d,%d), (%d,%d)\n", i, j, a[i], a[j]); //debug
                res++;
            }
        }
    }
///////////////////////////////////////// removing duplicate indexes //////
// credit: https://www.studytonight.com/c/programs/array/remove-duplicate-element-program
  int i, j, t, m=n*2;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < m; )
        {
            if (index[j] == index[i])
            {
                for (t = j; t < m; t++)
                {
                    index[t] = index[t + 1];
                }
                m--;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////averaging ///////////
  int arr[6],avg=0;
  for (int i = 0; i <4; i++ ) {
      arr[i]=a[index[i]];
      avg+=arr[i];
    
      printf( "a[%d] : %d\n", i, arr[i]); //debug
      
  }    
  avg/=4;
  printf( "Average : %d\n", avg); //debug
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return avg;
}



int main()
{
    int a[] = {30, 219, 220, 221, 216, 220};
    int k = 9;
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
  /////////////////////////////////
    printf("\nGiven array: {");
    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++ ) {
      printf("%d", a[i]);
      if(i<n-1){
        printf(", ");
      }
    }
    printf("}\n\n");
  /////////////////////////////////
  countPairs(a, n, k);
   ///////////////////////////////

    return 0;
}
```

### 4. Actual results including any error messages

There are two issues with this code:

1. the first valid index is missed. In my code, the output misses index 1 of given array which is element 219. How can I fix it? Currently it is based on variable J.
2. I cannot make the code generic and flexible in array sizes or loop numbers.

For example if you look at:

line 50 & 57-number 4 in :: *for (int i = 0; i <4; i++ )* and *avg/=4;*

line 47-number 6 in :: *arr[6]*

line 24 variable m- in :: m=n*2;  //this value is not logical, I just made it based on a simple guess

line 9-array size in :: index[n*2]; //this array size is not logical, I just made it based on a simple guess

A copy of my code, with line numbering, could be found at: `https://repl.it/repls/SuburbanRelevantDisassembly`

Looking forward to have your help/suggestions. Or do you suggest a better solution compared to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the problem completely, and when saw the code it was working, but I made my changes and it seem's to work fine.

```
int countPairs(int a[], int n, int k)
{
  printf( "n is %d \tand\t", n);
  printf( "k is %d\n\n", k);
  int index[n*2];
  int res = 0;

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
      if((a[j] - a[i]) < k){
        index[res] = a[i];
        res++;
      }
    }
  }

  int aux = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<res; i++)
    aux = aux + index[i];

  printf("Average: %d", aux/res);
  return aux/res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks André. But there are some issues with your code. 1. it duplicates elements of array and that can affect averaging part. 2.it doesn't consider the last element, 220.

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things that I noted:

1. You should be looking at the absolute value of the difference, otherwise order of numbers in your input matter and you'll be including values that shouldn't be included. For example, 30 - 200 = -170 and -170 is less than 7. Simply change `(a[j] - a[i])` to `abs(a[j] - a[i])`.
2. I think you should include both of the numbers from the difference comparison. If you compare `220` and `221` and their difference is within range, you want both of them in your output before duplicate removal.

Change

```
index[res] = j;
res++;
```

to

```
index[res] = j;
res++;
index[res] = i;
res++;
```

3. In your duplicate check, you're comparing indexes from your input array (populated during the difference checks) instead of the actual numbers. This will cause problems if the same number is included in your input twice. Instead of `index[j] == index[i]`, do `a[index[j]] == a[index[i]]` since `index` is an array of indexes for `a`
4. As for the harded-coded lengths and whatnot, you should be using the size of the initial input array. Look into dynamic memory allocation (`malloc` and `free`) to create arrays of a runtime-determined length.

This probably isn't everything, but hopefully will help you get started.

Comment: Thanks John for your suggestions. 1. That's right. 2.this solution is working, thx. 3.I don't want to remove duplicate elements as it can effect averaging part. That's why that duplicate removal part in my code way applied on indexes rather than elements. 4. I didn't get this part. How can I retrieve number of valid elements for those loops?

Comment: it'd be good to know how to set variable q on line 52 of this link https://repl.it/repls/SuburbanRelevantDisassembly to be generic. So that it'd work on larger or smaller size arrays, or those which might have two elements out of range e.g.{30, 66, 220, 221, 216, 220}.